# Android: Communication between Fragment and another Fragment directly on top of it

Tags: android, android-fragments

As I understand, if you want to communicate between 2 Fragments, you do that over the underlying activity. However, my 2 Fragments are not on the same hierarchy level, because 1 Fragment gets opened within/on top of another Fragment.

If I click a button on the overlaying Fragment, is there a way to communicate that directly to the holding Fragment, without going the detour over the Activity? Because that would be really messy.

A button click on Fragment 1 opens Fragment 2 in a FrameLayout IN Fragment 1. So it sounds like a big detour to send the Fragment 2 interaction to the underlying Activity and then back to Fragment 1.

If I understand it correctly, mListener is the Activity, not the Fragment which holds the 2nd Fragment

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd send it through the Activity.
But, you could use a message bus for this instead.